# Could UPnP control point display UI on Media Render

Tags: upnp, dlna

i've need to design UPnP control point device to remote control DLNA-certified TV box.

The question is could UPnP control point display UI on Media Render ? What I mean is how I could create simple control point device (like remote controller for TV), that have not any display, for example, someone could imagine UPnP Joystick.

For now, I see the only way is to send HTML (+Javasript) page to TV Box with my menu and then TV by javascript would subsribe to "cursor move" event on my control point device. And when I move my joystick to the left the cursor on TV also move to the left. Is it real scenario ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the device description of the TV box (or STB). This may contain a link to a UI to control the device, which might or might not (more likely) be helpful. If you want to roll your own, you are stuck with using the services exposed by the device.

Of course unless this device exposes other services like e.g. Samsung Smart TVs do, which expose a UPnP service to allow remote control of the TV. This is not part of DLNA though.

In essence, check out the UPnP device and service descriptions for your box and see what it offers you. You could use something like [Intel Device Spy](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-for-upnp-technology-download-tools/#anchor_2) to do this. I don't think you will be able to push HTML and JavaScript to your TV though. Instead you should rather implement the event handling for user input (touch, mousemove, whatever) on let's say a mobile device and use the exposed services via SOAP/UPnP.

Depending on what platform you are targeting, you will need to bring your own UPnP library for that. [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling) is a Java library that is supposed to work on Android too. It is not yet possible to use *only* Web technologies to implement a UPnP client (although with [NetworkServiceDiscovery](http://www.w3.org/TR/discovery-api/) it may be in the future).